# Highlight result text while using thsr:expand function of ML

Tags: marklogic

I am using MarkLogic THSR functions to create synonym of "Company" term. I am able to get desired result. When I am searching on the basis of "Company" term, I am getting text "Company" highlighted only. But, I need all the synonyms highlighted.

I am using cts:highlight to highlight text when displaying result.

My thesaurus XML is as under:

```
<thesaurus  xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/thesaurus">
  <entry>
    <term>Company</term>
    <synonym>
      <term>Services</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Industry</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Firm</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Business</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Corporation</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>House</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Establishment</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Agency</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Office</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Bureau</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Organization</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Institution</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Operation</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Enterprise</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Venture</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
    <synonym>
      <term>Undertaking</term>
      <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
    </synonym>
  </entry>
</thesaurus>
```

Is there any other way to highlight these things or I am doing anything wrong? Please help me.

My query to use thesaurus is as under:

```
cts:search(//TEXT, thsr:expand(cts:word-query("TEXT"),  thsr:lookup("/myThsrDocs/syn.xml", "TEXT"),(),(),()))
```

Comment: How are you using this thesaurus data? Post some code.

Comment: I have updated my Question please have look I just posted my cts:search query

Comment: The `cts:search` function is low-level. It returns a result set, and that's all. For highlighting you want `search:resolve`: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'd use [https://docs.marklogic.com/thsr:expand](https://docs.marklogic.com/thsr%3aexpand) to expand your query, then pass the results as XML to [https://docs.marklogic.com/search:resolve](https://docs.marklogic.com/search%3aresolve) which would do the highlighting.

```
search:resolve(
  document {
    thsr:expand(
      cts:word-query("Company"), $THESAURUS-ENTRIES, (), (), ()) }/*)
```

The `thsr:expand` function uses your initial `cts:query` item and your thesaurus entries to write an expanded query. The `document { ... }/*` expression turns that `cts:query` item into an XML element, which is what `search:resolve` expects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to run it but it is taking too much time (always time out) if compare to cts:search where I can define element "TEXT". More details of the document is that I have only one document in my DB which has 351 MB. I have inserted it through MLCP. I have "Fragment Parents" setting in my DB and I has almost 111,941 fragments. I need search on "TEXT" element only. Please suggest

Comment: Rethink that. Documents are rows, not tables.